# Probability that two Parts selected from a Normal Distribution are the similar length

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

So my problem is this:
I have a toleranced part with nominal length of 10mm and the tolerance is +-1mm, the distribution of these parts received follows a normal distribution with standard deviation is 0.333.

1. If I pick two parts from the distribution what is the likelyhood that the difference between the length of the two parts picked is 0.1mm or less.
2. If I pick 3 parts from the distribution what is the likelyhood that the difference between the length of the three parts picked is 0.1mm or less
3. If I have a batch of parts and I sort them into pairs where each pairing needs to be 0.1mm or less different in length what is the likelihood of this being possible?:
   - when the batch size is 10
   - when the batch size is 100

Any pointers in the right direction to tutorials of this type of problem or solution would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The difference between two normal random variables is also, conveniently, a normal random variable. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917276/distribution-of-the-difference-of-two-normal-random-variables/2049481. That should make the answer to 1 simple, and should also help with answering 2 and 3.

Comment: Welcome Chris! What do you mean by 'tolerance is 1mm'? You also state that the parts are normal with s.d. 0.333, do you mean that the parts are distributed according to $N(10, 0.333^2)$? If tolerance were to mean that the part is definitely between 9mm and 11mm in length, then the two statements wouldn't quite agree.

Comment: @Oxon A "tolerance" is a prescribed limit, in this case expressed as a difference relative to the nominal value. It needn't be related to the SD of the parts that have been manufactured, but typically--as stipulated here--that SD is substantially less than the tolerance, for otherwise many of the parts would likely be outside the tolerance limits. Part (2) requires the distribution of the range of a Normal sample while part (3) requires the distribution of the maximum difference between the even order statistics and the odd ones, which is an unusual problem but has good approximate solutions.